# Is it ok to call get_option without hooks?

Tags: plugins, options, performance, plugin-options

Many plugins call `get_option()` to fetch their settings right in the main plugin file, without using any action hook. **Is this the way it is meant to be used?**

I am asking because it seems to me that calling `get_option()` straight away has two downsides:

1. **Extensibility**: It makes it hard if not impossibile for devs to reliably filter the plugin options with the [`option_{$option}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/) filter. A workaround is to use a must-use plugin, but that is not always an option.
2. **Performance**: The options will be fetched at every pageload also if they are not needed (even though this is mitigated by the presence of the options cache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All options are loaded at pageload, because they include not only plugin/theme options, but also WP native stuff, like menus and widgets. Distinguishing between which ones to (not) load based on whether they are needed would take quite some calculations, so the performance issue you refer to doesn't exist.

Now about the extensibility. Let's take a look at the [WordPress action sequence](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). One of the first hooks you see is `plugins_loaded`. Any decent plugin would only initialize later, using the `init` hook. So, for extensibility you could hook into `plugins_loaded` to make sure your filter is in place before any call to `get_option`.

In the rare case where a plugin would simply start executing at load time, you would need your extension plugin to be loaded first. As you say you could write a [must use plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) for this. Or you could edit the option table to make sure your plugin is the first in the queue (yes, the list of plugins is also an option).

Now, finally, to your question: is this desirable? The fact that there are five different filters in the [`get_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) function certainly suggests so. However, if you are a plugin developer, would you like others to mess with your options without the user noticing? I'd say, if a plugin developer is explicitly not using the best practice of hooking his plugin options, maybe he simply does not want anybody to mess with those and you should respect that.

Comment: Thanks @cjbj! I see how `plugins_loaded` makes sense. Have a nice day, Guido